# react-native redux accessing / manipulating an object

Tags: json, react-native, react-redux

Hi I have this object and will have do some mathematical/statistical operations on it. Now I have to questions:

1. How do I access it? For Example I'd like to access numbers[0]['B1']
   When I do {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']} I get: Cannot read property B1 of undefined.
2. If I want to do some calculations on those numbers, where would I put them? From my limited experience with react redux, I know I should not do anything like that in reducers, am I right? Would I create more actions (action creators) to eg. get the average B1 number, or any statistical operations on the numbers, etc. Would it be recommended to use 'reselect' for this kind of tasks?

[image: The Object called numbers]

numReducer

```
import { LIST_NUMBERS, PICK_NUMBER, GET_DATA } from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default (state = [], action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIST_NUMBERS:
      return action.payload || [];
    case PICK_NUMBER:
      return action.payload;
    case GET_DATA:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

actions:

```
import { LIST_NUMBERS, PICK_NUMBER, GET_DATA } from './actionTypes';
import dataSet from '../data.json';

export const listNumbers = () => {
  const nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  return {
    type: LIST_NUMBERS,
    payload: nums
  };
};

export const getData = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA,
    payload: dataSet
  };
};

export const pickNumber = (num) => {
  return {
    type: PICK_NUMBER,
    payload: num
  };
};
```

data.json

```
[
  {
    "DrawDate": "22-Mar-17",
    "B1": 12,
    "B2": 6,
    "B3": 11,
    "B4": 31,
    "B5": 27,
    "B6": 19,
    "BB": 42,
    "BS": 1,
    "DrawNumber": 2217
  },
  {
    "DrawDate": "18-Mar-17",
    "B1": 26,
    "B2": 37,
    "B3": 8,
    "B4": 3,
    "B5": 19,
    "B6": 41,
    "BB": 43,
    "BS": 3,
    "DrawNumber": 2216
  },
....
```

Home Container

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { listNumbers, pickNumber, getData } from '../actions/numberActions';

import Home from '../components/Home';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  numbers: state.numbers
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    listNumbers,
    pickNumber,
    getData
  }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);
```

Home Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Screen',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

EDIT/ADDITION:

As per suggestions below, I've changed the lifecycle method to ComponentWillMount and added a check to see if this.props.numbers is loaded.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Screen',
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.numbers) {
       console.log('not yet loaded'); // or a spinner?
     }
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

I still get the same error: Cannot read property 'B1' of undefined. Additionally, the console does not log 'not yet loaded', which would indicate that the numbers object is there - I'm just making an error accessing it.

EDIT2:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Screen',
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }

  listNums() {
    return this.props.numbers.map((num) => num['B1']);
  }
  listSingleNum() {
    return this.props.numbers[0]['B1'];
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.props.numbers) {
       console.log('not yet loaded'); // or a spinner?
     } else {
       console.log(this.listNums());
     }
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.listNums()}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

So listNums() works fine displaying B1s of each element but if I try to access a single B1 element as in listSingleNum, it throws the error mentioned before: ExceptionsManager.js:63Cannot read property 'B1' of undefined.

Comment: what does the console.log(this.props.numbers) look like? maybe it is an empty array ? (´![] === false´)

Comment: I've updated the question. To answer your question: it shows it twice in console.log. First time it's [ ], second time it's the whole array as it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access it? For Example I'd like to access numbers[0]['B1'] When I do {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']} I get: Cannot read property B1 of undefined.

It looks like all your react/redux wiring is fine, its just that `getData` is getting called in `componentDidMount` so for the first render, the data is not not there yet (see the docs for [lifecycle methods order](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#mounting)).  You can use `componentWillMount` instead, but I'm still not sure if the data will be available on the first render.  To be safe, change the render function to do something different if `numbers` is `undefined` (you would have to do this anyway if you ever end up loading the data from a backend somewhere).

**NOTE:** The following is incorrect - see edit below

```
render() {
    if (!this.props.numbers) {
      return null; // or a spinner?
    }

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

> If I want to do some calculations on those numbers, where would I put them? From my limited experience with react redux, I know I should not do anything like that in reducers, am I right? Would I create more actions (action creators) to eg. get the average B1 number, or any statistical operations on the numbers, etc. Would it be recommended to use 'reselect' for this kind of tasks?

This will depend on how intensive the calculations are.  If the're pretty cheap, I'd just do them in the render function

```
import calculateAverage from './somewhere'

...

return (
  <View>
    <Text>####################</Text>
    <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
    <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']}</Text>
    <Text>Average: {calculateAverage(this.props.numbers.map((data) => data['B1'])}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Reselect is a good option if the calculation is expensive so that it doesn't unnecessarily recalculate the values every render.  It's also nicer for testing than having the logic in the component itself.

**EDIT:** Wow... I'm feeling a bit silly at the moment...

`this.props.numbers` is not undefined (it's defined by the initial state of the reducer).  If you check for length it will render (I've replicated all this code and run it myself to be sure this time).

```
render() {
    if (this.props.numbers.length === 0) {
      return null; // or a spinner?
    }

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>####################</Text>
        <Text>Intro Screen</Text>
        <Text>Number: {this.props.numbers[0]['B1']}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

It is important to actually return something (or `null`) within the if statement so that it doesn't hit the `undefined` value (`this.props.numbers[0]`).

---

**Explanation** (requested in comments)

It all boils down to the [component's lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

When the component mounts it has an empty array, set by the `initialState` of the reducer

```
export default (state = [], action = {}) => {
  ...
};
```

The [mounting lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#mounting) will fire in order.  When the `componentDidMount` (or `componentWillMount` depending on which update of the question we are at) the state is replaced in the redux store to have the full data set.

After the mounting lifecycle has completed the react-redux will change trigger the props to change, firing off the [updating lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#updating).

During this stage render is called again, this time with the correct data.

So the component wont "keep re-rendering until the numbers object is not empty", it will re-render whenever the props change, and if the numbers array is not empty, will include desired components.

Returning `null` is [valid in react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering) and is commonly used to prevent components from trying to access props that are not available yet.

Comment: Thanks - valid points unfortunately I don't think it's the case here. I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you seeing your log message? If you don't return within that block, you will still get the undefined error.

Comment: Ok. That works - so hold on. How does it work? Does it keep re-rendering until the numbers object is not empty?

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer, but basically it boils down to component lifecycle.